# HELP: How to compute a mean for specific cases, NOT the entire dataset!

Tags: spss, mean

I am trying to compute a mean of several variables for just two cases, rather than compute the mean of several variables and include all the cases in the dataset. How does one do this?

Thank you for any help, it is very much appreciated. -S.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because, according to your comment, it is about how to use SPSS rather than about Statistics. Try one of the SPSS support sites listed [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software).

Comment: "Just two specific cases" or "Every two cases?" Aka, are you trying to compute the mean of only ID 1 and ID 2, OR are you trying to compute the mean of ID 1 & ID 2, ID 2 & ID 3, ID 3 & ID 4, and so on so forth?

Answer (score 5):

You add the two values you want and divide that sum by two.

Comment: Hi Maarten, thank you for your response. What I'm trying to do is compute the mean for say 2, 3, or 4 cases out of a total number of 22 cases. I'm using SPSS 20 and I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I believe I need to start at Transform -> Compute Variable, right? Ty!

Comment: Seth - how was anyone to guess that you were asking about how to do it in SPSS, unless you told us that's what you wanted in the question?